# Timer not working properly

Tags: ios, nstimer

I am having issue with running a method on certain time interval. I have a method for it. From what I see is that the variable that stores second value(mynumber) is not read properly.mynumber is suppose to hold 200 seconds extracted from the website but it seems not to be working. The displayinterstitial is called in rather short time.I am hoping to get some pointers towards the right direction.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection
{
  NSString *theResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[webData mutableBytes] 
                                                 length:[webData length]
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSLog(@"xml : %@",theResult); 
  mynumber =[theResult doubleValue];
}

-(void)test
{
  if(Callcount ==1)
  {
    [self performSelector:@selector(displayInterstitial)
               withObject:nil
               afterDelay:mynumber];
    }
 }
```

Comment: "mynumber is suppose to hold 200 seconds extracted". You say "suppose" not "does" So how about logging the result of mynumber for starter.

Comment: @MartinH Actually it does hold 200 double value extracted from the website.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly, `test` is called prior to `connectionDidFinishLoading`, or `mynumber` is not 200 at the point that `test` is called. Have you verified the order that these are called? Have you verified the value of `mynumber` at the point that `test` is called?

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that the value is 200 at the point performSelector is called, not at the point the value is assigned to mynumber?  How are you checking, I don't see any calls to NSLog in the test function.

If it is 200 then are you sure you are not running the code several times in a row and the short fire times are actually previous calls to performSelector which are just now expiring?